# Universal links are not working when attached to a notification

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, push-notification, react-native, deep-linking

Hello all and thanks in advance,
I'm trying to implement the universal links feature in my react native app in order to receive push notifications with links from Marketing Cloud and bring the user to the right screen.
Everything works fine if I put the link inside a Note and I click on it: the continueUserActivity method defined in AppDelegate.m is triggered and the url is passed to the app.
The problem comes if I send the link from Marketing Cloud: when I tap on the notification the continueUserActivity method is not triggered.
Looking at the debug console in xcode I found that error:

`[foundation] URL https://dev15.cdn.blablabla.ows.farm was NOT handled - the URL handling delegate method was NOT implemented or delegate nil`

This is the payload received from MC:

```
[opendirectmessage] Notification received with userInfo {
    "_h" = VJQqaBW72XjQXvc6H5COjwAAAAAA;
    "_m" = MTUxOjExNDow;
    "_mt" = 1;
    "_od" = "https://dev15.cdn.xxxxx.ows.farm";
    "_r" = "a799093b-c03b-4577-907b-7e6d7fc9218f";
    "_sid" = SFMC;
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = nvnvh;
            title = "MC Push is calling";
        };
        "mutable-content" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the URLs within your application.  See [iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/implementation-urlhandling.html) and [ANDROID](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/url-handling.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm trying to implement method sfmc_handle in my AppDelegate.m file in order to pass url to react native but I'm not skilled on IOS native development, do you have any example on how to do it?

Comment: I made it by myself, I don't know if it's the best way but it works:
```
- (void)sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *)url type:(NSString *)type {
  NSLog(@"Handling open direct url coming from Marketing Cloud");
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
  [appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:dict];
}
```